# gprof issue with output

Tags: c++, gprof, profiling, xlc

The question is: Why is my gprof output only displaying "Index by function name" ?

I have compiled my application with the support of this tutorial :
http://ececmpsysweb.groups.et.byu.net/cmpsys.2004.winter/citizenship/Bryan_Wheeler/Profiling_Tutorial.html

So my application is compiled with -p -pg

After i run my application with ./application it will create the mon.out file, but this only holds the Index by function name, which is kinda strange,

Has anybody had the same expirience or knows what iam doing wrong here.

Thanks, Alcatros

Comment: Was your application linked with profiling enabled (e.g. via `gcc -p -pg file1.o file2.o -o program`)? There is documentation from gprof in how to compile and link: http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/gprof/Compiling.html#Compiling

Comment: Thanks for the note, yes i did link it with the -p -pg flag because i have multiple objects to glue together, but iam not using cc or gcc , i use xlC or also known as VACC 7.0 , it also works on small hello world programs but for some reason not on my application

Comment: Take [a look at this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem was that putty was somehow hiding the output, after opening vi and exiting it, it would actually show the output from the program.